# Difference among OCI driver, Thin driver, Data Source - OracleDataSource?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver

I am Using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition with Java.

**Link:**

http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/oracle/java.html

3 types of connections with different drivers are depicted

i want to know that *can all these 3 connection be made in any situation or these are used in specific cases ?*

Answer (score 0):

The 2/3 are almost the same. Both of them uses jdbc:oracle:thin driver. The only difference is the invoker (DriverManager vs. OracleDataSource).

The 1st uses oci driver (jdbc:oracle:oci8). This is totally different with thin driver. Thin driver is 100% implemented in Java. So no more library is needed. But OCI driver needs Oracle OCI client, which is implemented in C/C++ (You must install it before you use the oci driver). As a result, it is platform dependent (C/C++ library).

Some people thinks the performance of OCI is better than thin, because OCI is implemented in native C/C++. But Oracle never releases an official document to prove that.

Now most apps use thin driver, because it is easy to deploy (Do not need the Oracle OCI client). And to be decoupled with the Oracle classes (OracleDatasource), most people use DriverManager to load the oracle thin driver, or a Connection Pool.